# How to determine at run-time if app is distributed for internal or external tester?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, app-store-connect, testflight

I know that it is possible to determine if an app is installed through TestFlight or AppStore. But for those app installed through TestFlight, is it possible to know if they are distributed for internal or external tester?
Thanks.

Comment: I don't think its possible since its the same binary. Only the distribution to different people differs

Comment: ITunes connect shows you who installed your app. If that is not sufficient you'll need to track your users independently. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app does not know where it comes from. You have to handle this information by yourself.

1) Identify your users one by one and decide whether they are internal or external testers

2) Make a custom build for internal/external testers. In this case you can add new a new target for your project and only change one variable in the build settings to differentiate internal/external build.

Here you can find an example of use of multi target project :
http://www.raywenderlich.com/68613/create-paid-lite-version-iphone-app